# Can't get texts on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to get multiple custom texts on cell of UITableView. I want these texts after clicking on a dynamically added button on the cell. I can't use ***didRowSelectedAtIndex*** method. I have my own selector which I am executing but I don't know how can I get texts on each cell. Anybody can help me?

Thank

Comment: You're probably going to have to add some code so people can get an idea of what might be going wrong.

Comment: Code will be either too long and pieces at different places..I tried to explain it through words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your labels as global variables
2. Create yur cell as default style cell.
3. Add your labels to contentView of cell without text.
4. Add your button.
5. In the method that button invokes after click set texts to your labels.

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   customLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 20)];
   customLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 5, 50, 20)];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:customLabel1];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:customLabel2];
   }
   ```

and

```
    - (IBAction) click
    {
        customLabel1.text = @"YAYA";
        customLabel2.text = @"GAGA";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You add a UILabel to the cell's view. Just like you did it with your custom Button.

You can add a UILabel to all cells in advance. If the UIButton on a cell is cklicked, you have to save that state information somewhere (NSArray). When it comes to rendering the cell, you ask the array if the cell at current index should show some text and set it up if so...

If you want immediate rendering call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (array at index indicates clicked) {
        myCustomCell.label1 = @"foo";
    } else {
        myCustomCell.label1 = @"bar";
    }
}
```

If you don't like customs cells. You can apply a tag to the label, add the label to the cell and get it from cell by querying it afterwards by that tag.

Comment: Yes I have three UILabels added in the contentView of cell. But cells are to be added dynamically at runtime. SO can't put all labels in NSArray in advance. I actually want to know that on which cell the button added was clicked so that I can get texts on that cell.

Comment: 1. You don't save the labels in the Array, but the information, if the cell was clicked. 2. When it comes to rendering the cells, consider that information an set the text of teh label.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try creating a custom button class by extending UIButton and add properties to contain references to the NSString objects (or index of the original array where the strings are stored etc).

Then on button click you can cast the sender to your custom button type and simply retrieve the property values.